# Trouble getting background color to apply to a form

Tags: html, css

I have a form I'm using to add a record to a database.  The form works perfectly, but I'm trying to add some color to the background so it stands out from the rest of the page.  The CSS I'm using lets me style the size of the form, border weight, etc. but nothing I do changes the background color.

```
 <p class="first"><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
  <form action="http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/NewProject.php" method="post">

    <div class="fieldset">
        <fieldset>

        Project: <input type="text" name="Project" value="<?php if(isset($Project)){ echo $Project; } ?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php if(isset($ProjectErr)){ echo $ProjectErr; } ?></span>
        <br><br>
        Client: <input type="text" name="Client" value="<?php if(isset($Client)){ echo $Client; } ?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php if(isset($ClientErr)){ echo $ClientErr; } ?></span>
        <br><br>
        LastName: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="<?php if(isset($LastName)){ echo $LastName; } ?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php if(isset($LastNameErr)){ echo $LastNameErr; } ?></span>
        <br><br>
        DateReceived: <input type="text" name="DateReceived" value="<?php if(isset($DateReceived)){ echo $DateReceived; } ?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php if(isset($DateReceivedErr)){ echo $DateReceivedErr; } ?></span>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
        </fieldset>
    </div>
  </form>


div.fieldset {
    border: solid black thin;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: #3ffffb0;
    margin: auto;
}

fieldset {
    border: none;
    padding: 10;
    }

input.textbox {
    width: 400px;
    float: right;
}

fieldset p {
    clear: both;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: You put too many digits there, should be 6 instead of 7.

Comment: `#3ffffb0` is an invalid hex colour code

Comment: Are you trying to give the whole lot a background colour to sit on, or just colour the background of each input?

Comment: Why do you have both `<div class="fieldset">` and `<fieldset>`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`#3ffffb0;` isn't a colour. CSS hexadecimal colour codes have 3 or 6 numbers, not 7.

You probably mean `#3fffb0;`.

This would have been picked up if you had used [a validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).

Comment: Ummm, I can't believe I screwed with this for 30 minutes and didn't realize I had too many characters in the color.  Thanks for pointing it out and thanks for not calling me an idiot either haha!!  I didn't think to use a validator because it wasn't a lot of code I was looking at.

Answer (score 0):

You have one too many digits in your background-property in your css.

It should be:

```
div.fieldset {
border: solid black thin;
width: 500px;
background-color: #3ffffb;
margin: auto;
}
```